# jquery addclass for custom validations

Tags: jquery

I have this script in jquery to validate a dropdown, textbox. The user should enter either dropdown or textbox and not both

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id*=btnSubmit]').click(function () {
            var ddlDiscountPercentVal = $('select[id*=ddlMktPercentages] option:selected').val();
            var txtDiscountValueVal = $('input[id*=TxtDiscountValue]').val();
            if ((ddlDiscountPercentVal == 0 && txtDiscountValueVal == '') || (ddlDiscountPercentVal != 0 && txtDiscountValueVal != 0)) {
                alert('please enter a value other than 0 for percentage or enter a value');
                return false
            }
            else

                return true;

        });

    });
```

Now instead of the alert box, I want a proper error message with a color and the position of the error. Should I be using the jquery validate library

Any hints. Thanks for your help
Sun

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a **modal dialog**.

There's lots of plug-ins for those too:

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/